# LinearLayout with weight-attributes on children inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout

The usual question regarding ScrollViews seems to be how to use fillViewport to let the ScrollView stretch to the whole screen. My problem is similar, but going the other way :)

I got a LinearLayout that contains multiple elements. All except one element have a fixed height, the special one is an ImageView that should stretch to fill the remaining space. This works fine :)

Now I want to put the LinearLayout into a ScrollView, as some of my elements should expand at runtime (e.g. click on "more"-icon that expands a TextView). In the unexpanded version I would like to have all elements fit on the screen, as if the ScrollView wouldn't exist.

Unfortunately, when wrapping the ScrollView around the LinearLayout, the ImageView is scaled to maxSize und the screen does not fit the screen. Do you have any ideas how to achieve my goal?

I reproduced the problem in an example app to share it with you:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffff0000"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/background" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#ff00ff00"
        android:text="element 2"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="#ff00ff00"
            android:text="element 1"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here are the screenshots from the two versions:

[image: Screenshot inside ScrollView (notice the scrollbar and cropping on element 1)] [image: Screenshot without ScrollView]

The one above is the Layout with ScrollView (notice the scrollbar and cropping on element 1),  the one below without.

**Update:** The original height of the image in the image-view is bigger than the screen. So it should be downscaled (that's why it has weight 1 and scaleType set).

**Solution: The following code solved the problem for me (based on Luksprog answer)**

Main Activity (excerpt, change of layout is induced by click on ImageView):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroller);
    frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

    final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            frame.removeView(layout);
            scrollView.addView(layout);
            image.getLayoutParams().height = image.getHeight();
        }
    });

}
```

Layout XML file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffff0000"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/background" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="#ff00ff00"
            android:text="element 2"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="#ff00ff00"
            android:text="element 1"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:background="#ff00ff00"
            android:text="element 3"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I don't know if you can do it only from the xml(but it's too late to think). You could always do it manually: Set a `FrameLayout` as the root of your layout, in which you'll add the `ScrollView` and above it the `LinearLayout`(to which you'll keep a reference). This will be the `closed` position. If the user wants more you then detach the `LinearLayout` from the initial `FrameLayout` and add it to the `ScrollView`. You'll reverse the process when the user collapses the more option. This could lead to visual glitches.

Comment: Doing it in xml is not a must :) How would you handle attaching / de-attaching the layouts? Calling `removeView(linLayout)` on the rootLayout and calling `addView(linLayout)` on the ScrollView?

Comment: Yes, remove the LinearLayout from the main layout and reattach it to the `ScrollView`. You could try it and see how it goes. The main problem, I think, will be that the `ImageView` could be resized when it will be placed in the `ScrollView` and I don't know how good will that look(going to a greater size). But test it and see how it behaves, if it doesn't work maybe I could suggest something else.

Comment: Thank you, that brought me a step forward. Switching from FrameLayout to ScrollView works, however, as you predicted, the ImageView is getting resized during the transition. Could I get the size of the `ImageView` before the transistion and set it after moving the view around?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will do the trick, but you can get the height of the `ImageView` after `onCreate` and then modify its `LayoutParams` when you do the switch. You would do this with a `Runnable`: `aViewFromTheLayout.post(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() {mHeight = imageView.getLayoutParams().height}});`. Then you could use `mHeight` to set the same height for the `ImageView` wherever you want(get its `LayoutParams` and modify the height to `mHeight`). See how it goes.

Comment: Thank you very much Luksprog! (... pressing enter in comments, will submit it :)) I created for demo purposes a simple onClickListener on the picture `int height = image.getHeight(); frame.removeView(layout);scrollView.addView(layout);image.getLayoutParams().height = height;` and it worked :) The `.post(...)` is needed if  I want to do this inside `onCreate` as no layouting took place when it is called, right? Do you want to create an answer, so I can give you the appropriate kudos? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comments, I don't know if what you're trying to do is possible at the xml level. One option would be to modify your current layout and add a root `FrameLayout` to which you'll, initially, add the `ScrollView` and above it, the `LinearLayout`. In this position the `ImageView` will behave as you want as the user didn't modify the layout. When you need to show more in your layout you'll detach the `LinearLayout` from the view hierarchy(with `removeView`) and attach it to the `ScrollView`(with `addView`). You'll reverse this when the user goes back to the initial layout.

This will make the `ImageView` to have different heights when making the views switch so you'd want to get the height of the `ImageView` and re set it when doing the switch. To get the height, you could do it in a listener or using the `post` method in `onCreate`(as the views haven't been laid out yet at that moment). Also, remember that the user could turn the phone, I don't know if this will affect your layout, but take it consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i tried running your code and it didn't cause any issue for me. The scrollView did not show up although the image was scaled to a ScreenHeight-160dp height which i expected because you have used weight 1 for this imageview.

I would suggest that you remove the weight and give height as wrapcontent. In that case the Imageview will just enclose the Image. When it becomes bigger in size, automatically scrollview come into use if the total heights of all screen contents is more than the screenheight.

Comment: I updated my question with information on the image in the ImageView. Following your example: if the image is bigger than screenheight-160dp  you get exactly the layout problem I sketched in my screenshots.